# Iterate through a table finding a td by class and changing the text for that td

Tags: jquery, html, entity-framework-4, html-table

I have an Entity Framework generated table with values in a td that I need to change. I need to do this on a row by row basis because I need to insert a group of radio buttons but each row of buttons needs a unique name.

Basically, I need to set the checked value for a group of buttons based on the value of the text in a td with id of "Rate", and remove the existing text after I have got the value from it.

My Table looks like this,

```
<table id="IndexTable">
<tr>
    <th>CoffeeID </th>
    <th>Degree </th>
    <th>Weight </th>
    <th>Profile </th>
    <th>UsageInfo </th>
    <th>Comments </th>
    <th>AmbientTemp </th>
    <th>Rating </th>
    <th>WeightDeducted </th>
    <th>Selected </th>
    <th>ProfileID </th>
    <th>ProfileStart </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>9 </td>
    <td>Filter Brew </td>
    <td>Perfecto!! </td>
    <td>55 </td>
    <td id="Rating">4.25 </td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>4 </td>
    <td>34 </td>
    <td>1 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>15 </td>
    <td>99 </td>
    <td>87 </td>
    <td>Espresso </td>
    <td>WTF </td>
    <td>99 </td>
    <td id="Rating">4.5 </td>
    <td>5 </td>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>66 </td>
    <td>4 </td>

</tr>
```

And my script is as follows.

```
$("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table
var str = $("text[id=Rating]").val(); //assign text with matching id to str ---doesn't work
$("td").each(function() { //get all tds in current row
    var newStr = ("#Rating").text; //assign text in td with id Rating to newStr ---- doesn't work
    alert(newStr); // fires undefined for each td in table? 
    //This is where I want to insert radio buttons and assign the one with the value of the Rating td to checked.
});
});
```

This is just the latest, I have looked all over this site, but everything I've seen doesn't deal with getting the value from a specific column of a specific row, changing the value, and repeating for each row/column in the table.
I come from a db background, where this is really simple and this is very frustrating.

Comment: where are you planning on putting the radio buttons?

Comment: ID should be unique across DOM. You cannot have more than one `id="Rating"` in a html document.

Comment: I want to replace the text in the td with the rating 'class as pointed out' with radio buttons and check the one matching the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong with your html, and your jQuery,   to start off, like SKS has stated, you cannot have multiple nodes in your html document that have the same ID. ID must be unique.  I recommend using a class instead.

You should also have your header row in a `<thead>` and the body of your table in a `<tbody>`

now, onto your jQuery,  `$("td")` will find all the td's in the document, not just the ones in your row.

you would want to use
`$(this).find('td')` or you could use .children  or a fancy higher level selector.  There are MANY different, correct ways to get this information.

I have taking your code and modified it like so:

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table

    var ratingTdText = $(this).find('td.Rating').text(); 
    //gets the text out of the rating td for this row
    alert(ratingTdText);

});
```

This works with the html slightly modified:

```
<table id="IndexTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>CoffeeID </th>
    <th>Degree </th>
    <th>Weight </th>
    <th>Profile </th>
    <th>UsageInfo </th>
    <th>Comments </th>
    <th>AmbientTemp </th>
    <th>Rating </th>
    <th>WeightDeducted </th>
    <th>Selected </th>
    <th>ProfileID </th>
    <th>ProfileStart </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>9 </td>
    <td>Filter Brew </td>
    <td>Perfecto!! </td>
    <td>55 </td>
    <td class="Rating">4.25 </td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>4 </td>
    <td>34 </td>
    <td>1 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>15 </td>
    <td>99 </td>
    <td>87 </td>
    <td>Espresso </td>
    <td>WTF </td>
    <td>99 </td>
    <td class="Rating">4.5 </td>
    <td>5 </td>
    <td>3 </td>
    <td>66 </td>
    <td>4 </td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps get you going in the right direction!

oh, i almost forgot!  here is a link to a jsfiddle so you can see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fCpc6/

Comment: Thanks Patricia! I noticed you answered a similar question for Roger, but I am new to jQuery, and couldn't figure out how to modify it for my use.

Comment: my pleasure, jquery can be a little overwhelming at first.  You should spend some time looking though the documentation for selectors. it will help you out a lot.

Comment: I have been Patricia, it's just confusing because all their examples seem to be single case, and figuring out how to use them together is what's throwing me.
Now I just have to figure out how to replace the value in the cell with my radios.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
var newStr = ("#Rating").text();
```

Or:

```
var newStr = ("td[id='Rating']").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your javascript.

- Use `this` to get `td`s that belong to the current `tr`.
- `"text[id=Rating]"` is an invalid selector - there is no text tag.
- `#Rating` should probably be a class, since IDs must be unique. (change `<td id="Rating">` to `<td class="rating">`.
- You were missing parentheses on `.text()`.

Here's an updated sample:

```
$("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table
  $("td", this).each(function() { //get all tds in current row
    var newStr = $(".rating").text(); //assign text in td with id Rating to newStr ---- doesn't work
    alert(newStr); // fires undefined for each td in table? 
    //This is where I want to insert radio buttons and assign the one with the value of the Rating td to checked.
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I'm going with Patricia's only because it doesn't loop as much. I appreciate it! And thanks for pointing out the unique id issue in the Html!!